# Custom Outline mode key binding

Tags: key-bindings, outline-mode

I want to set a key binding for `outline-next-visible-heading` but I fail to do so.
I believe using hooks is a solution for this so I added this to my `.emacs`

```
(defun outline-mode-test-hook()
  (define-key outline-mode-prefix-map "j" 'outline-next-visible-heading))
(add-hook 'outline-mode-hook 'outline-mode-test-hook)
```

The key binding has no effect.

P.S. Who actually runs `outline-mode-hook` ? I didn't see any invocation within file `outline.el`.

Comment: The hook is no doubt invoked by `outline-mode`.

Comment: @Drew: I don't understand why you think a function-vs-command confusion might be linked to the user's problem.

Comment: @Pommy: Can you describe what you tried to do, which made you think "the key binding" has no effect?  E.g. what key have you pressed which you thought would trigger the command?

Comment: @Stefan: Oops, my bad; sorry. I didn't pay attention to the code.

Comment: @Stefan I have `(setq outline-minor-mode-prefix "\C-co")` set so all of my outline commands are prefixed with `Ctrl-c o` and work fine. When I type `Ctrl-c o j` nothing happens. If I manually (using `C-x C-e`) execute define-key directive custom key binding start to work. But of course I need it to be done automatically on startup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question doesn't mention it, but your comment hints at the fact that you're using `outline-minor-mode` rather than `outline-mode`.

`outline-mode-hook` is run when you enter the `outline-mode` major mode.  Since you use `outline-minor-mode` that hook is not run, instead the `outline-minor-mode-hook` is run, hence you'd need something like:

```
(add-hook 'outline-minor-mode-hook #'outline-mode-test-hook)
```

Another option is to use

```
(with-eval-after-load 'outline
  (define-key outline-mode-prefix-map "j" 'outline-next-visible-heading))
```